# Issue with vg-scrub-bar in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic2, videogular

Getting error as :
Can't bind to 'vgSlider' since it isn't a known property of 'vg-scrub-bar-current-time'.

1. If 'vg-scrub-bar-current-time' is an Angular component and it has 'vgSlider' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'vg-scrub-bar-current-time' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
                                                                             ("ss" *ngIf="showTimeDisplay">
                                                                                               
                                                                                                   ][vgSlider]="true">

Used code:

```
<vg-scrub-bar style="pointer-events: all;">
    <vg-scrub-bar-current-time [vgSlider]="true"></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
</vg-scrub-bar>
```

Comment: do you have imported ```import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';```

Comment: Which videogular2 version are you using? I think `vgSlider` is not supported in previous versions.